# PC keeps powering off

Tags: power

Sorry if asking in wrong place and I'm not sure what info is needed to properly answer so I'll add more info as i can going on.

I have some old pc (around 7 years) and lately it started to power off automatically. Sometimes after 2 seconds before even seeing the boot screen, sometimes while windows is loading and sometimes i even reach the login.

I read that it could be a bad psu so i bought a newer stronger one. Had around 400w and now 520w. 
However the issue remains and since it is also happeing before windows even loads I am pretty sure its a HW issue.
Also read that the cpu fan might return some error so the cpu shuts down but the fan is working so can't really tell if that's the case.

Not sure what more to look at. 
Would appreciate any ideas. Thanks

Small update. With the new psu it always shuts down during windows loading not boot screen.
Also when booting there are 4 leds lighting up and after few seconds shut down. Then when pc shuts down those 4 leds flash and pc dies. Maybe that tells something. The writing next to it is phaseled.
Looks like maybe something is short-circuiting but can't say.

Comment: Sometimes helps just disconnecting and reconnecting all parts. Especially RAM modules are prone for bad contacts. If you have two RAM modules, try first with only one, then with only other. Check temperatures in BIOS (find health page). Get SMART of your HD by connecting it to other PC and using for example speedfan or crystal info.

Comment: I do have 2 ram units. I will try disconnecting one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Windows button: typ in 'Event Log' see if you can see any critical events that may have caused your crashes. This way you can give us some info we can do with.

Comment: Windows doesnt start. I just disconnected harddrive and graphics card and it still shuts down. I think it's a short-circuit or something :(

Comment: So it might be the PSU or your motherboard.

Comment: I switched to a new psu. So ya probably motherboard.

Comment: Most of the times, If you can't adres the error MOBA is the issue.